# React native How to return a value from a function to the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-router

Im getting the 2 user authenticated from firebase database but how can I return a value from the function or is there any other solution to the authenticated user

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {

```
            firebase.database().ref('Usersyeah/').on('child_added', function (getdata) {



                var newData = getdata.val().User

                if (user.email == getdata.val().Email ){

                    if (getdata.val().User === 'User') {
                        var routes = [
                            {title: "Home",route: "Home",}
                            {title: "Pending Request",route: "Request"}]
                    } else {
                        var routes = [
                        {title: "USER",route: "Home"}
                        ]
                    }   
                }
                 getdata.val().User })
            });

        } else {

        }
    })



    return (

        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', margin: 10, padding: 10 }}
                onPress={this.mysubmit.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={{ color: '#fff', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}> SUBMIT </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
                style={{ width: 250, height: 200 }}
                source={require('../myimage/durian.jpg')}

            />
            {
                routes.map(e => (
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.link} onPress={_ => this.navigate(e.route)}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{e.title}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )
                )
            }
        </View>
    )

}
```

Comment: use promise to resolve the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way could be to declare an instance variable on component like

```
myComponent{
    constructor(props){
        this.valToBeReturned;
    }
}
```

And then, inside function you can initialize it with the value you want:

```
theFunction(user=>{
    this.valToBeReturned = getdata.val().User //for example
})
```

In this way, you have the value you want on this.valToBeReturned outside the function scope.